# Objective-C - Canceling a thread?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsthread

I have a search function in my app where the user types in the textField, and as the text changes I am searching the local database and populating data in a table.

The search might take anywhere between 1 to 10 seconds depending on the text entered, so I decided to use a thread. Every time the text changes I want to cancel the thread (If running already), and start it again with the new keyword. The problem is that according to the documentation calling cancel doesn't guaranty that the thread will be killed. So what is the solution here?

Is there any way to kill a thread?

```
- (void)populateData
{
   if (self.searchThread.isExecuting)
   {
       [self.searchThread cancel];
   }

   [self.searchThread start];
}

- (void)populateDataInBackground
{
   @autoreleasepool
   {
      // get data from db
      // populate table on main thread
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want the thread to die necessarily, as it will be reused later (making threads is expensive).  What you should do is break your work into as many pieces as you can, and in between each piece check to see if your thread's `isCancelled` property is `YES`.  If so, return without the update.

`[NSThread currentThread]` should return your thread while you are inside `populateDataInBackground`

Comment: There is 1 line of code to get the data from db, and 1 line to populate the table, I don't know how I could break it into pieces :)

Comment: Then I guess you just have to check in between those two lines.  I'm guessing most of the work is in the first step, and the update of the table is trivial.  I doubt you are allowed to kill execution of things at whim.  You could call exit on the thread, but the documentation warns not to.  You might just need to use cancel as a flag on whether to update the table or not.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up modifying my dataStorage to return 10 items at a time, just for testing. I might use another number later. This way I can exit the thread in my while loop.

Another advantage is that this way I can populate the table as I go through the items, instead of waiting for all data to be retrieved.

```
@interface ViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSthread *searchThread;

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize searchThread = _searchThread;

- (void)populateData
{
   [self.searchThread cancel];

   self.searchThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(populateDataInBackground) object:nil];
   [self.searchThread start];
}

- (void)populateDataInBackground
{
   @autoreleasepool
   {
      [self.array removeAllObjects];

      // I added paging functionality to my sql, so I get let's say 10 records at a time
      while (/*has data*/)
      {
          NSArray *arrayOf10 = [self.dataStorage getdatafromIndex:startingIndex withCount:10];

          if ([[NSThread currentThread] isCancelled])
               [NSThread exit];

          [self.array addObjects:arrayOf10];
          [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@Selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
      }
   }
}

@end
```

Comment: So in other words "break your work into as many pieces as you can" ?? ;) ;)

Comment: Yes, I posted this answer just for future reference :)

Answer (score 1):

One of a few possible solutions would include this:

Set some "`BOOL`" semaphore / property from your main thread (e.g. "`searchNow`") and read it periodically while you're going through your "`populateData`" background thread / task.

If the state changes to "NO" (assuming "`searchNow`" == YES implies that the task should continue), then exit your background thread.

Comment: How do I exit a background thread? cancel doesn't exit the thread right away.

Comment: if your thread is running within some loop (e.g. "`do { } while ( searchNow == YES );`), then the thread will exit.  And @borrrden's suggestion is also good (+1 to him), but I don't think threads are *that* expensive to set up, especially if you're only bringing it up during the occasional text entry.