# Tableview scrolling crashes app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsthread

I am developing iPhone app in which i am downloading image from server in background,

Here is view of my application,

[image]
when i click on `Button 1` i am fetching 5 data from server also images, after fetching data when user scrolls up i am fetching new 5 data from server again when user scrolls up i am fetching new 5 data from server and so on.

while fetching data for `Button 1` if i click on `Button 2` am cancelling my previous thread of `Button 1` and  i am fetching new 5 data for `Button 2` and on scrolling it again fetching new 5 data **Same as Button 1**

but after some time while reloading a tableview my app gets crashes and shows:
**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: ' -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 28 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]**

Here is my code snippet:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        [self fetchDataForButton1]; 

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {


                [tableView reloadData];


        });
    });

}


- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
 if(it is last row then fetch new 5 data)
 {
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

                        //Code runs on background thread
                        [self LoadMoreData];

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {

                            //Code here is run on the main thread
                            [_tblList reloadData];

                        });
                    });


      }else{
              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

                                [self beginBackgroundFetchTask];

                               [self downloadImage_3:indexPath];

                                [self endBackgroundFetchTask];
                            });
      } 

}


-(void)downloadImage_3:(NSIndexPath *)path{


        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImagePath]]];

        if (img) {
            [dicImages_msg setObject:img forKey:[[msg_array objectAtIndex:path.row] valueForKey:@"Merchant_SmallImage"]];
        }

        [_tblList performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];


}

- (void) beginBackgroundFetchTask
{
   self.backgroundFetchTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [self endBackgroundFetchTask];
    }];
}

- (void) endBackgroundFetchTask
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask: self.backgroundFetchTask];
    self.backgroundFetchTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    NSLog(@"ended BackgroundFetchTask");
}

-(void)LoadMoreData
{
   //Fetches new 5 data from server...
}
```

Comment: try debugging your app, put a breakpoint on cellForRowAtIndexPath. See when the array goes out of bounds. The error you are getting is because the array gets null value on a particular indexPath.row.

Comment: **reason: [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 28 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]**, you are trying to access object at index 28 but your array has just 5 elements

Comment: You are correct dude, but when i click on `Button 2` i have stopped fetching data of `Button 1` and i am initializing my array and again fetching new data for `Button 2` but crashing occurs because it still fetching data of `Button 1` index **28** is of `Button 1` how should i stop my thread of `Button 1`? on click of `Button 2`

Comment: Why are you copying and pasting the same response to every single answer. People are trying to help you here.

Comment: Sorry dude but i got stuck here since last 4 days and unable to find answer :(

Comment: @Krunal try holding the second loading while the first loading is under process and once first loading is done then activate the second load function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem maybe at `[self downloadImage_3:indexPath];` you call `dispatch_async` when you at `Button1`, and the `dispatch_async` block have not invoked, then you click on `Button2`, then I guess `msg_array` is cleared and filled with new 5 object, after that, `dispatch_async` block is invoked, the `path.row` for block is 28, whereas, the `msg_array` has new array content with 5 new objects, then crash.

You should cancel `dispatch_async` before click on other button, which is impossible for `dispatch_async` , so you can have a judgement in block:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    [self beginBackgroundFetchTask];

    [self downloadImage_3:indexPath buttonIndex:index];

    [self endBackgroundFetchTask];
});

-(void)downloadImage_3:(NSIndexPath *)path buttonIndex:(int)buttonIndex{
     if(self.currentSelectIndex != buttonIndex) return; //skip reloadData if not same index


        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImagePath]]];

        if (img) {
            [dicImages_msg setObject:img forKey:[[msg_array objectAtIndex:path.row] valueForKey:@"Merchant_SmallImage"]];
        }

        [_tblList performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

}
```

Comment: yes dude you are very correct same thing is happening here.

Comment: But the problem is `downloadImage_3` is getting called for every cell if i skip for same index then how will i fetch image for same index on scrolling?

Comment: @Krunal. As I comment, skip reloadData if not same index, you only need care data refresh while the data affect current selected view.

Comment: `[self downloadImage_3:indexPath buttonIndex:index];` here how should i identify `index` ?

Comment: I think ImagePath got relative to index, just same way to pass index to downloadImage_3. Above is just my guess, u must have a logic about index, try to pass to downloadImage_3.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

1) Use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for fetching Images from Server

2) Use [Pull Refresher](https://github.com/pilot34/MNMBottomPullToRefresh) feature for fetching next 5 data.

This will helps to fetch data in background.

Comment: You are correct dude, but when i click on `Button 2` i have stopped fetching data of `Button 1` and i am initializing my array and again fetching new data for `Button 2` but crashing occurs because it still fetching data of `Button 1` index **28** is of `Button 1` how should i stop my thread of `Button 1`? on click of `Button 2`

Comment: To stop thread refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553863/objective-c-canceling-a-thread

Answer (score 0):

Use SDWebImage for fetching Images from Server.

Comment: You are correct dude, but when i click on `Button 2` i have stopped fetching data of `Button 1` and i am initializing my array and again fetching new data for `Button 2` but crashing occurs because it still fetching data of `Button 1` index **28** is of `Button 1` how should i stop my thread of `Button 1`? on click of `Button 2`

Answer (score 0):

AS per your log array is having only 5 count and you are fetching the data as per `indexpath.row` and in this crash case is **28**. So it might be that you are adjusting your cell indexpath row according to your new array which is fetching again and again data on scrolling but in the repetition of **5**.

Just put a breakpoint and check whether you are resetting the indexpath row in count of **[0 4]**;

**UPDATED:**

```
[[NSThread currentThread]  populateDataInBackground];
```

Comment: You are correct dude, but when i click on `Button 2` i have stopped fetching data of `Button 1` and i am initializing my array and again fetching new data for `Button 2` but crashing occurs because it still fetching data of `Button 1` index **28** is of `Button 1` how should i stop my thread of `Button 1`? on click of `Button 2`

Answer (score 0):

This is because images take time to load from server and cell gets no data when it is allocated.

You need to implement lazy loading for it.

[Here](http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.in/2013/04/lazy-image-loading.html) is a good tutorial.

Comment: You are correct dude, but when i click on `Button 2` i have stopped fetching data of `Button 1` and i am initializing my array and again fetching new data for `Button 2` but crashing occurs because it still fetching data of `Button 1` index **28** is of `Button 1` how should i stop my thread of `Button 1`? on click of `Button 2`

Answer (score 0):

Disable user interaction then go to top on table:

```
 [TableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];
```

then call:

```
 [TableView reloadData];
```

then enable userintercation.
hope will solve the problem

Comment: You are correct dude, but when i click on `Button 2` i have stopped fetching data of `Button 1` and i am initializing my array and again fetching new data for `Button 2` but crashing occurs because it still fetching data of `Button 1` index **28** is of `Button 1` how should i stop my thread of `Button 1`? on click of `Button 2`

Answer (score 0):

I would not fetch data like that from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. That is used to display cells.

Instead do it like this:

1. List your original data.
2. When the user scrolls past the last cell, show a footer that displays a loading symbol.
3. at the same time While the footer is displaying a loading symbol, then and ONLY then call the `fetchLoadData` method, and WAIT
4. Until you dont hear from the server, continue displaying the loading symbol, dont start adding new cells to prepare for anything, because chances are you might either not get anymore data back, which at this point you have to get rid of the footer cell and let the user know that there is no more data to retrieve, OR if there is more data to display, THEN set up your next 5 cells by doing the following in this order:

   - adding your new 5 data objects to your data array
   - updating the number of rows in section using the `numberOfRowsInSection` delegate method
   - You will find that your cells if coded correctly will be displayed correctly once you refresh the table using `[myTable reloadTable];`